# alloc, malloc, and alloca — What's the difference?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc, alloca

I was under the impression that `alloc` in Objective-C (when we invoke `[anyObject alloc]` is actually implementing C function `malloc` and the memory getting allocated in heap, but could not find anywhere the answer for this.

Also, while searching for `alloc`, I found `alloca` which allocates memory in stack. If I am not wrong, `alloc` allocates memory in heap to create objects.

So, what is the difference between `alloc` and `malloc` (and `alloca`)? Can anyone please summarize?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`alloc()` is not a standard C library function. Some older compilers and libraries contain an `<alloc.h>` library which provides some memory allocation functions, but this is not standard. The Microsoft Visual C++ runtime includes an `Alloc()` function which is somewhat similar to `malloc()`, but this is also not part of the C standard.

`malloc()` allocates memory on the process heap. Memory allocated using `malloc()` will remain on the heap until it is freed using `free()`.

`alloca()` allocates memory within the current function's stack frame. Memory allocated using `alloca()` will be removed from the stack when the current function returns. `alloca()` is limited to small allocations.

Situations where `alloca()` is appropriate are rare. In almost all situations, you should use `malloc()` to allocate memory.

Comment: "Situations where alloca() is appropriate are rare. In almost all situations, you should use malloc() to allocate memory."  No.  All `alloca()` does is provide variable length arrays.  There's no practical difference between `int n = 6; double x[n];` and `int n = 6; double *x = alloca( n * sizeof( *x ) );`  Not only that, the use of `malloc()` in multithreaded programs can be a severe performance bottleneck.

Comment: My query was more in terms of Objective-C which implements `[[someObject alloc] init]` to allocate the memory and initialize the object in heap. Does this `[someObject alloc]` implements `malloc` in the background?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I didn't say that there are *no* situations where `alloca()` is appropriate; I said that they're rare. VLAs are one case where they're useful, but even there they're essentially an optimization. Since the OP is clearly new to C programming, I opted to not go to deep into the details. :)

Comment: @AnindyaSengupta Your question didn't mention Objective-C, so I didn't consider that as a possibility. Yes, the `+[NSObject alloc]` method will most likely call `malloc()`, or something functionally equivalent.

Comment: @Andrew Henle, there is **real** practical difference between `alloca` and VLA's if you use in a loop.

Comment: So `alloca()` is garbage-collected `malloc()`? Sweet!

Comment: @étale-cohomology I’d hesitate to call it “garbage collected”. Frame-local, sure. But nothing fancier than that.

Comment: failed to mention that `alloca()` is apparently BSD\GNU and isn't in standard of C or POSIX

Comment: also memory still need to be freed, it's not freed automatically if pointer goes out of scope, it's freed only when function returns.

Answer (score -6):

The `alloc` function is used to allocate a region or block of size bytes in length of the `heap`.

The `malloc` function is used to allocate `heap` storage. Its name stands for memory allocation.

Comment: Please look at this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be handy to lift your quality up

Answer (score -10):

I don't remember the verbatim statement from the book C++ Primer, but there is a major difference between the functions. For example new in C++ allocates memory, but it also constructs the data into the memory. The std::allocator allocates memory, but doesn't call any constructor. The same is true for these C functions. One allocates but doesn't construct. One allocates and construct.