# Pointer in the definition of a function

Tags: c

I am learning c, however i understand the concept of pointers but here i am having trouble.What is mean by a pointer in the definition of a function. Here v is a local pointer defined within the function so returning it means that only the values will be copied and returned or a pointer to that block will be returned because what i also learnt that local variables have only life time until the function executes. Will someone like to explain, will be a great help.

```
struct verpl * nieuw (int van, int naar, int aantal, register struct verplaatsing * lijst)
{
   register struct verpl * v = (struct verpl *) alloc(sizeof(struct verpl));
   aNieuw++;
   v->van = van;
   v->naar = naar;
   v->aantal = aantal;
    v->volg = lijst; // plaats het element vooraan in de lijst
     return (v);
}
```

Function call

```
 lijst = nieuw (via, huidig->naar, huidig->aantal - 1, lijst);
```

Comment: First of all: remove the`register` s; they can only do harm.(second: remove the cast)

Comment: are you sure of `alloc` ?

Comment: I don't see why you are passing `lijst` as an argument for the function parameter `struct verplaatsing *` but then assigning the function return value to it, which is type `struct verpl *`. They are different types.

Comment: pls divide so long sentence, hard to understand is correctly

Comment: @WeatherVane  there are 3 recursive calls and lijst is self a pointer.

Comment: I see no recursive call, and that doesn't explain why you use the same variable for two different types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is returned is the *pointer value* returned from `alloc()`.

`v` is local and returning *a pointer pointing to `v`* is not good, but what `v` is pointing is not local, so returning it is valid.

Comment: `alloc()` ? isn't that `malloc` ? if it's `alloca` then there's a problem.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `alloc()` exists as non-standard library. [c - alloc, malloc, and alloca — What's the difference? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685851/alloc-malloc-and-alloca-whats-the-difference) I don't know if it is typo of `malloc` or `alloca`.

Comment: if it's a typo of `alloca` then the code is wrong as it returns a reference on temporary memory.