# Channel/BlockingCollection alloc free alternatives?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, producer-consumer, system.threading.channels

I recently benchmarked my framework and noticed that it allocates tons of garbage.

I'm using a `Channel<T>` and the `TryRead` or `ReadAsync` operation allocates memory every single call. So I exchanged that with a `BlockingCollection<T>` which also allocates memory during `TryTake`.

I used a unbounded channel with a single writer/reader. And a normal `BlockingCollection<T>`.

```
// Each thread runs this, jobmeta is justa struct 
while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    var jobMeta = await Reader.ReadAsync(token);  // <- allocs here
    jobMeta.Job.Execute();
    jobMeta.JobHandle.Notify();
}
```

The profiler told me that all allocations are caused by the `ChannelReader.ReadAsync` method. Unfortunately I can't show the full code, however since I use them in a hot path, I need to avoid allocations at all cost.

Are there any alternatives which do not allocate memory during read/write/get and behave the same (Concurrent classes for producer/consumer multithreading) ? How could I implement one by myself?

Comment: Please improve the title as the phrase "free alternatives" is very ambiguous and misleading.

Comment: ​@Dharman it's "alloc free alternatives", not just "free alternatives". Alloc is a [well recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685851/alloc-malloc-and-alloca-whats-the-difference) abbreviation of "allocation" in computer jargon. The title could be changed to "allocation-free alternatives", but I wouldn't consider it a significant improvement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [System.Threading.Channels](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/main/src/libraries/System.Threading.Channels/src/System/Threading/Channels) library currently has three built-in `Channel<T>` implementations:

- [`UnboundedChannel<T>`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Threading.Channels/src/System/Threading/Channels/UnboundedChannel.cs)
- [`SingleConsumerUnboundedChannel<T>`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Threading.Channels/src/System/Threading/Channels/SingleConsumerUnboundedChannel.cs)
- [`BoundedChannel<T>`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Threading.Channels/src/System/Threading/Channels/BoundedChannel.cs)

From those implementations, the less allocatey is the `BoundedChannel<T>`. If you don't want bounds, you can configure it with `capacity: Int32.MaxValue`. The `UnboundedChannel<T>` is based internally on a `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, which is a very performant and non-contentious collection (it's lock-free). The allocations are a necessary compromise for being lock-free. The `BoundedChannel<T>` is based on an internal `Deque<T>` collection, which is synchronized with `lock`s. It allocates memory only when it has to expand the capacity of it's backing array, which will happen only a few times during the lifetime of the channel.

The `BlockingCollection<T>` is also based on a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` by default, so it has the same advantages and disadvantages. If you want to reduce the allocations (reducing also the performance and increasing the contention), you could implement an `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>` based on a synchronized `Queue<T>`, and pass it as an argument to the `BlockingCollection<T>` constructor. You could use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470196/concurrent-collection-with-priority/71483676#71483676) as a starting point.

Finally passing `CancellationToken`s to any of these APIs will result to allocations no matter what. The `CancellationToken` must register a callback in order to have instantaneous effect, and callbacks without allocations are not possible. My suggestion is to get rid of the `CancellationToken`, and find some other way of completing gracefully. Like using the [`ChannelWriter<T>.Complete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelwriter-1.complete) or the [`BlockingCollection<T>.CompleteAdding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.completeadding) methods.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an alternative type but an alternative way of using Channels. Instead of cancelling the reader, close the writer. This is the technique used in the .NET RabbitMQ client.

Besides, it's far more important to ensure that the payload doesn't require lots of allocations. If you use ArrayPool to reduce allocations you can't just abort the worker method, you need to retrieve the messages and release them.

**Channels in RabbitMQ**

RabbitMQ uses Channels in the hottest path - when [writing message frames to the network stream](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/blob/5b925e39be2a9c26a8651383817e3c89fcefe83a/projects/RabbitMQ.Client/client/impl/SocketFrameHandler.cs#L287) and when receiving bytes. Few libraries handle more traffic than RabbitMQ. Kestrel itself is one of them, and the use case is similar. Both are expected to handle millions of requests/messages without overhead.

Writing is handled by the `WriteLoop` method which runs in a background task:

```
_writerTask = Task.Run(WriteLoop);
```

The [WriteLoop](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/blob/5b925e39be2a9c26a8651383817e3c89fcefe83a/projects/RabbitMQ.Client/client/impl/SocketFrameHandler.cs#L287) method itself doesn't cancel. If it did, it would risk leaving a message unfinished.

```
    private async Task WriteLoop()
    {
        try
        {
            while (await _channelReader.WaitToReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                while (_channelReader.TryRead(out ReadOnlyMemory<byte> memory))
                {
                    MemoryMarshal.TryGetArray(memory, out ArraySegment<byte> segment);
#if NETSTANDARD
                    await _writer.WriteAsync(segment.Array, segment.Offset, segment.Count).ConfigureAwait(false);
#else
                    await _writer.WriteAsync(memory).ConfigureAwait(false);
#endif
                    RabbitMqClientEventSource.Log.CommandSent(segment.Count);
                    ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(segment.Array);
                }

                await _writer.FlushAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ESLog.Error("Background socket write loop has crashed", ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

In this code `_writer` is a [buffered network stream](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/blob/5b925e39be2a9c26a8651383817e3c89fcefe83a/projects/RabbitMQ.Client/client/impl/SocketFrameHandler.cs#L148):

```
_writer = new BufferedStream(netstream, _socket.Client.SendBufferSize);
```

The [Write](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/blob/5b925e39be2a9c26a8651383817e3c89fcefe83a/projects/RabbitMQ.Client/client/impl/SocketFrameHandler.cs#L282) method is only a call to `_channelWriter.TryWrite` so it doesn't have to check whether the writer is closed or not

```
    public void Write(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> memory)
    {
        _channelWriter.TryWrite(memory);
    }
```

`Cancelling` means calling [Close](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/blob/5b925e39be2a9c26a8651383817e3c89fcefe83a/projects/RabbitMQ.Client/client/impl/SocketFrameHandler.cs#L205) which completes the writer and once the pipeline completes, closes the socket :

```
try
{
    _channelWriter.Complete();
    _writerTask?.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
catch
{
    // ignore, we are closing anyway
}

try
{
    _socket.Close();
}
catch
{
    // ignore, we are closing anyway
}
finally
{
    _closed = true;
}
```

This ensures that any pending messages are still processed.

It's far more important to ensure that the payload doesn't require lots of allocations. RabbitMQ uses a `Channel.CreateUnbounded<ReadOnlyMemory<byte>>`. The buffer itself comes from `ArrayPool<byte>.Shared`. Once a frame is sent, the buffer is released back to the pool

```
ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(segment.Array);
```

**Nuking the Pipeline without leaking buffers**

In normal operation you wouldn't need to cancel anyway. You'd only need that if you had to nuke the pipeline instead of stopping the publisher. One such case could be that a downstream worker can't process messages any more, because a network connection was terminated. In this case, calling `Complete` on the publisher could still leave messages in the Channel that can no longer be processed.

The cooperative way to handle this is to discard the messages if cancellation is signaled, not cancel the `Read` operation itself. If we use ArrayPool we *must* receive those buffers to release them anyway.

The RabbitMQ code doesn't work this way, but handling this needs only a simple change in the inner loop:

```
        while (await _channelReader.WaitToReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            while (_channelReader.TryRead(out ReadOnlyMemory<byte> memory))
            {
                MemoryMarshal.TryGetArray(memory, out ArraySegment<byte> segment);
                if(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    // Normal processing
                }

                ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(segment.Array);
            }

            await _writer.FlushAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

This ensures the worker method stops processing messages immediately without leaking buffers.

**Structs and multi-threaded workers in RabbitMQ**

RabbitMQ uses the same pattern in the [ConsumerDispatcherChannelBase](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/blob/5b925e39be2a9c26a8651383817e3c89fcefe83a/projects/RabbitMQ.Client/client/impl/ConsumerDispatching/ConsumerDispatcherChannelBase.cs#L22) class. In this case the payload is a readonly struct [WorkStruct](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/blob/5b925e39be2a9c26a8651383817e3c89fcefe83a/projects/RabbitMQ.Client/client/impl/ConsumerDispatching/ConsumerDispatcherChannelBase.cs#L104) which also holds a pooled buffer, [RentedArray](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/blob/5b925e39be2a9c26a8651383817e3c89fcefe83a/projects/RabbitMQ.Client/client/impl/ConsumerDispatching/ConsumerDispatcherChannelBase.cs#L115).

The difference this time is that there can be multiple consumers for the same RabbitMQ connection, so the class can start multiple worker tasks :

```
        Func<Task> loopStart = ProcessChannelAsync;
        if (concurrency == 1)
        {
            _worker = Task.Run(loopStart);
        }
        else
        {
            var tasks = new Task[concurrency];
            for (int i = 0; i < concurrency; i++)
            {
                tasks[i] = Task.Run(loopStart);
            }
            _worker = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }
```

Shutting down works the same though. Complete the writer and wait for the workers to exit :

```
    protected override Task InternalShutdownAsync()
    {
        _writer.Complete();
        return _worker;
    }
```